# Organizational Chart node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, charts

i'm developing an application and i need to build like this one in the photo. All the blocks are optionals, but the position needs to be the same. I'm using react for frontend and nodejs for the backend. Is it possible to do it with some npm ? Thanks

[image]